# Angular 2.0 ng-for not displaying values inside html tags

Tags: javascript, components, angular

I'm building dynamically links in the footer of a small app I'm developing using Angular 2.0. So, I have this for the footer component:

```
// the main footer object ..
function FooterComponent() {

    // define the links in the footer ..
    this.footerLinks = [
        {
            'iconName': 'users',
            'title': 'Friends'
        },
        {
            'iconName': 'list-bullet',
            'title': 'List'
        },
        {
            'iconName': 'cog',
            'title': 'Settings'
        }
    ];
}
FooterComponent.annotations = [
    new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
        selector: 'fly-footer'
    }),
    new angular.ViewAnnotation({
        directives: [angular.NgFor],
        templateUrl: 'templates/footer.html'
    })
];
```

and in the view I have tried these variants so far:

```
<div *ng-for="#footerLink of footerLinks">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="footer-link demo-icon icon-{{footerLink.iconName}}">{{footerLink.title}}</a>
</div>
```

and

```
<a href="javascript:;" *ng-for="#footerLink of footerLinks" class="footer-link demo-icon icon-{{footerLink.iconName}}">{{footerLink.title}}</a>
```

And the result is that in neither of them the icon name doesn't render. Instead I see (for class of the links):

```
class="footer-link demo-icon icon-{{footerLink.iconName}} ng-binding"
```

The title appears as expected.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

```
class="footer-link demo-icon icon-{{footerLink.iconName}}"
```

is a raw string, while you are expecting it to behave like an expression.

You want to do this

```
class="footer-link demo-icon" [class]="'icon-'+footerLink.iconName"
```

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YX6FBKo4qp6pRvRivWsm?p=preview).

PS : I don't recommend you at all to stick to old versions. The documentation is outdated (being updated constantly but still outdated) and the new alpha versions are changing constantly (with a lot of breaking changes). You should stick always to the last alpha version until a stable version is released.

Comment: Unfortunately, all my attempts to include the "CSSClass" directive cause error "Cannot find 'keyValDiff' pipe supporting object 'ng-binding' in [ng-binding in ...". Without including the directive - I don't get error, but the class is not applied. And when I tried to switch to #34 - then error appears on the way I've done the annotations. (new angular.ComponentAnnotation... - "angular is not defined" ...)

Comment: I'll try with the typescript version ... using the ES5 version for now looks like mission impossible ... :( and also - the typescript code I'll have to write - doesn't seem to need changes through the alpha versions.

Comment: Finally I did it :) [class] and "CSSClass" did the job :) ... (but now I'm using Angular2 with TypeScript, and not ES5 :( ...)

Answer (score 0):

You should add [CSSClass](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/directives/CSSClass-class.html) to list of your view directives:

```js
new angular.ViewAnnotation({
    directives: [angular.NgFor, angular.CSSClass],
    templateUrl: 'templates/footer.html'
})
```

Also take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yyoy7T593DvXoNyF0Zav?p=preview)

Comment: Unfortunately, when I added it, it gave me an error: "Cannot find 'keyValDiff' pipe supporting object 'ng-binding' in [ng-binding in FooterComponent]".

Comment: (You're using #34 of Angular2, while I'm with #26 - the version on the official docs.)

Comment: @peshohristov: You should be using the latest version, which is `alpha-34`. The official documentation is very old and outdated right now so you cannot trust it.

Comment: From what I can see the documentation is not so far off. If you check ComponentAnnotation of instance it's well updated with bindings and viewBindings. I believe they regenerate the documentation from source files anyways so it should be more or less in sync with the state of the framework, even though a lot is still missing and examples are very limited in most cases. Nevertheless, keep on updating your project as alpha releases come otherwise you'll have a very hard time later on and you might face bugs that are fixed in the current version.

Comment: When I tried to recreate the plunker locally - it gave me this error: '"Potentially unhandled rejection [3] Error loading "main.js" at http://localhost/Angular2/hello/main.js
Not Found: http://localhost/Angular2/hello/main.js (WARNING: non-Error used)"' ... :( ...

Comment: (I raised a question for that btw ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093809/simple-angular-2-app-gives-potentially-unhandled-rejection-error ...)