# Simple Angular 2 app gives "Potentially unhandled rejection" error

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this very basic example:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>FlyLeaf</title>
        <script src="js/lib/system.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <main-app></main-app>

        <script>
            System.config({
                paths: {
                    'app.js': 'js/app.js'
                }
            });
            System.import('app.js');
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

and inside app.js:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-app'
})
@View({
    directives: [CSSClass, NgFor],
    template: `
        <h1>My first Angular 2 App</h1>
    `
})

class MainApp {
    constructor() {
        this.footerLinks = [];
    }
}

bootstrap(MainApp);
```

and gives me exactly this error:

```
"Potentially unhandled rejection [3] Error loading "app.js" at http://localhost/HelloWorld/js/app.js
http://localhost/HelloWorld/js/app.js:3:1: Unexpected token @ (WARNING: non-Error used)"
```

I saw it working on a plunker, and locally it doesn't ... :(

(on both Firefox & Chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I can see the error, you are missing [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures#annotations-experimental) which will let you to use annotations

So add this in your HTML (see that is even added in the docs under [6. Declare the HTML](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html))

```
<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
```

and in your System.config add these options

```
System.config({
    traceurOptions: {
       annotations: true,
       types: true,
       memberVariables: true
   },
//...
```

Finally, as a recommendation, use the System.import like this

```
System.import("your.app").catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

With this you'll be able to catch some more errors.

Give it a try and you should good to go.

Comment: Yes, after added loading the traceur and the config options - then it ran :) (It had syntax error though, for first line of app.js - "import{Composer...". But it was working ... :D ...)

Comment: Now the syntax error is gone. What I did is that I downloaded four files - angular2.dev.js (from #32), system.js, traceur-runtime.js and es6-module-loader@0.16.6.js - in the "lib" folder and made the HTML load them from there, and now all is fine - I have all necessary locally, and my code is working :) ...